# What is in_app_purchase refers to

Tags: in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I don't understand what in_app_purchase refers to. I thought that it refers to a functionality like Screen A will be disabled until a payment is made. From online information, it seems like in_app_purchase refers to products to sell through the app.

It is not about a functionality to buy.

I am bit confused like what type of products you would see in your app. A mobile app is not a regular e-commerce store.

On Google Play, I've seen quite a number of apps (not a game) have in_app_purchases. From many app descriptions, it is not clear what is included in the in-app purchase.

Typically, for a software program, you could see based on a plan by plan basis how each plan is different like what functionality is included in each plan.

With the in-app purchase, it is very blurry what is included in the in-app purchases.

Could you please provide examples and explain.